# Add directives to apache vhosts - clear log

Tags: apache-2.2

I have this directive on each of my virtual host. It is eating all my hard drive space very very quickly and have to clear it manually. I need some directives added to my ghosts.

For each virtual host in httpd_vhosts.conf, I have this line.

```
ErrorLog /Library/WebServer/thisHostsDirectory/err_thisvhost.log
```

1. How do I tell apache to clear the log every xx days.
2. How do I add  in the directive to log the remote IP on this log
3. How do I exclude my localhost and other specific IPs on this log.

Thank you.

Comment: What's filling the log?  Fix the root cause, not the symptom - the error log typically won't be terribly large.

Comment: Its that particular line above. I had to delete that log (475gb) yesterday. I have 3 vhosts in one Lion server.

Comment: Funny thing is, it does not happen on the other server running Leopard where I have 3 vhosts. Only on the new Lion Server. Have the same directive except I am using the Lion as proxy for the Leopard.

Comment: That line directs the Apache server to place the error log there - the error log ***must*** be somewhere, so that line is not the issue.  What I'm looking to find out is the contents of that log file - it's completely abnormal for it to get that large.  Most likely you've got something like `LogLevel debug` configured somewhere, or a bot making an enormous number of requests to a nonexistant file.  Let's get a small sampling of the log - run `tail /Library/WebServer/thisHostsDirectory/err_thisvhost.log` in the terminal application.

Comment: OK - I just ran it and this what I got. It was emptied yesterday.

Comment: how do I paste it here. its a little too long for this comment area.

Comment: Edit your question with the new information - there's a little 'edit' button on the bottom left, under the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to handle this is to add the webserver logfile to `rotatelogs`. This rotates the log either after set size reached and|or after a set time.

Do a `man rotatelogs` on your system to find out how this works.

**UPDATE**
Just forgot to mention that you should pipe the rotated logfile to a compression program to get the logs archived.

About what to add just check the documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html and here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

To answer your 2.) you would have to add a `%a` in your `CustomLog` directive. For 3.) someone else might suggest a solution. I'd pipe the output to awk or sed and remove the lines starting with either 127.0.0.1 and|or localhost. But there might be better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to rotate Apache logs :

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs /var/logs/errorlog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M"
```

The documentation has everything you need: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

Comment: Shall I add it to each vhost before my err log line?